# HTTP 401 error for every Yammer Rest API call for a given Network

Tags: rest, http-status-code-401, yammer

We're experiencing a very weird issue concerning Authentication & Yammer API http requests:
We have as app that makes request using the Rest API and authentication token. Everything works great.. except for one network where every single request fails with a HTTP 401 error.

We are currently successfully requesting more than 30 other networks, so we suppose that the issue is not caused by the application (even if we check that first).
We can't figure out why we got all those errors only on that Network. Moreover, the same code used to work one week ago on that Network and we didn't change anything related to authentication for weeks.
We check the Network security parameters, and we already know that:

- the application was not revoked from the Network
- the application token did not expire
- the Network allows all ips to connect to (in Network Security Settings)

So we're currently running out of idea..
Does anyone have a clue about what's happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally found the solution. In Administration>Configuration, the "3rd Party Applications" feature has been disabled by an Administrator.

Answer (score 3):

The 401 on networks is likely because the Yammer network turned off 3rd party applications. In a Yammer network's Network Admin settings, admins can disable 3rd Party Applications in the Network Admin > Configuration settings. This will prevent any 3rd party application from authenticating with any user from that network.